# UserAuthRole created even if UseDistinctRoleTables is false

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

When *not* using separate table for Role, e.g. `UseDistinctRoleTables=false` why is `UserAuthRole` table still created? I checked the source code, which has if-clauses for UseDistinctRoleTables many places, but not in `InitSchema()`.

It is confusing to have empty tables that are not in use. Is there a purpose, or could this be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's not necessary for it to be generated which has been resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e2a1eb7f2cc6bb0bf3da77fe63ae634e762e12bb).

This change is available from the latest v5.11.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Fixed within the hour. That's why I recommend ServiceStack to everyone I meet. And it's been like this for years and years. This is not a "thank you" comment, I honestly think it's useful for people to know the excellent level of service one can expect.

Comment: I confirm, the support level is outstanding.